# Different Color Background in my AlertDialog in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, popup, window

A very weird thing is happening with my custom Alert dialog. Same code when run different times, yields different background color of the Alert Dialog layout, of which most of the times the color is red (out of no where!), even though I have used a different background to the layout. Take a look at my code first.

**This is the layout for the AlertDialog**`(layout_add_url.xml)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:id="@+id/url_layout_constraint"
    android:background="@drawable/background_note"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

//Some  ImageViews and TextViews here
```

This is what `layout_add_url.xml` has finally

[image]

Now,

**This is the background_note.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#333333"/>             //Note that the color here is black
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/_10sdp"/>
</shape>
```

This is where I have finally created the **AlertDialog** in my Kotlin Activity

```
 val inflater = layoutInflater
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_add_url, null)
            val infoDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@CreateNotesActivity)
            infoDialogBuilder.setView(view)
            val infoDialog = infoDialogBuilder.create()
            infoDialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            infoDialog.setContentView(view)
            infoDialog.show()
```

***But after Running the project on a real device. It looks like this***

[image]

**Note**
I have noticed that when I change the `android:background="@drawable/background_note"` to `android:background="#333333"` the code then seems to work fine

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the background of your dialog via a style property and use the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`.

Remove the `android:background="@drawable/background_note"` property from the `ConstraintLayout` in `layout_add_url`

Define your dialog style in `style.xml`:

```
<style name="style_dialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceMediumComponent">@style/style_dialog_background</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">#333333</item>
</style>

<style name="style_dialog_background" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.MediumComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">@dimen/_10sdp</item>
</style>
```

Then create your dialog by calling:

```
val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_add_url, null)
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this@CreateNotesActivity, R.style.style_dialog)
        .setView(dialogView)
        .create().apply {
            show()
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will surely give this a try.

Comment: Also, I replaced my `background_note.xml` with another `background_note1.xml` (which has the same elements) and everything seems to be working fine. IDK how this happened but everything's good for now. My guess is that maybe it happened because the activity on which I have opened the dialog, has the same background(`background_note.xml`) as the dialog itself. But even if that's that I can't still find out the reason why.

Comment: I checked your solution on my code, but it still does not work . Same red color prevails. :(

Comment: Try to remove the attribute `android:background="@drawable/background_note"` from the `ConstraintLayout` in `layout_add_url`

Comment: I did that and then my background is all white!

Comment: Ok, so I edited my answer to this issue. You should set the `colorSurface` property in your `style.xml` to obtain the correct background color. It should work now.